# Removing public folder from URL with htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I am bugged by the public folder in the URL. I searched internet for removing it and found the following ways.

Way I: 
Move all the files and folder except public folder to a newly created folder in the root directory then copy all the files from public folder to root folder.

Way II:
Copy the .htaccess file from the public folder to root folder and rename the server.php file present in the root folder to index.php

Way III:
Create a .htaccess file in the root folder and paste the following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

The Issue is The Way I and Way II are working fine but are not considered safe since they are exposing .env directory and other directory. Many developers are saying that changing the root to public folder (Way III) is the correct way but when i am doing this i am getting error page of larave.

How to Resolve it?
Which is the better approach to remove public folder from URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to set your document root to your public folder.

On your hosting, add AddOn domain and give path as:

path: domain_root_folder/public/

You domain will be propagated as www.example.com instead of www.example.com/public/

Answer (score -1):

First way which is more secure:

1. Move the Laravel project out of `var/www/html` to `var/laravel`
2. Copy the content of /public to /var/wwww
3. Edit `index.php` to point to laravel new location (locations of `/vendor/autoload.php` & `bootstrap/app.php`)
4. Leave apache config file as it was before ('or htaccess')
5. You are good to go

Second way: (Your way)

Comment: When i use this method then i am able to access the folder in which i've kept the laravel file which seems to be a problem

Comment: it's impossible cuz apache serve content from var/wwww or var/www/html, it can't access the parent directory, just the index.php can